# Proving $G$ is a subgroup of the group Sym$_\mathbb R$ for all bijective maps from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

So $G=\{f(x)=ax+b|a,b \in\mathbb R,a\neq0\}$, I want to prove that it is a subgroup of the group Sym$_\mathbb R$ consisting of  all bijective maps from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

I am aware the subgroup test states the following:

For a non empty subset $H ⊆ G$ the following are
equivalent:

(i)$ H $ is a subgroup of $G$,

$(ii)$ $hh' ∈ H$ and $h^{-1} ∈ H$ for all $h, h' ∈ H$,

$(iii)$ $hh^{−1} ∈ H$ for all $h, h^{-1} ∈ H$

So now when I try to apply it, from my understanding $G$ is a subgroup of Sym$_\mathbb R$ if $(i)$ and $(ii)$ are true.

However, doesn't that mean I need to show the following is true for the second condition:

$(ax_1+b)(ax_2+b)$ must create a bijective function.

$\Rightarrow$ $a^2(x_1x_2)+ab(x_1+x_2)+b^2= K$

But how can this be true, if quadratic equations dont have an inverse thus cannot be bijective?

Comment: I see now this is not a quadratic in terms of $x$ so what I said isn't true, but regardless how could I even show that function is bijective?

Comment: Your mistake is that you multiply them. You should combine them as functions.

Comment: The group of bijective maps $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a group with the operation of composition, not product. $hh'(x)$ means, in this case, $h\circ h'(x)$.

Comment: @flytothesurface so I should in fact be trying to show that $a(ax_2+b)+b$ is bijective?

Comment: @N.K yes that's it.

Comment: @quid Thank you, also one other question if anyone wouldn't mind helping. For the subgroup test, as it states those 3 conditions are equivalent, does that then mean it is enough to only show either $(ii)$ or $(iii)$ is true? Or is it necessary to show both are true.

Comment: @N.K either is fine..

Comment: Your "subgropu test" has some problems with it. First, (iii) doesn't make sense, $hh^{-1}=e$ so it should be in $H$ as long as $H$ is a subgroup, but converse isn't true. $hh^{-1}\in H$ for all $h\in H$ doesn't mean $H$ is a subgroup. Correct condition should be $h_1h_2^{-1}\in H$ for all $h_1,h_2\in H$.  (ii) is a definition of subgroup. Above all, none of your (ii) and (iii) mention that $e$ should be in $H$; by your conditions ii and iii $\emptyset$ is a subgropu of $G$, which is absurd

Comment: @user160738 the last point of your objection is not valid as it is asserted before that H is non empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you say correctly the conditions are equivalent. Thus if one is true all are true. You need to show (i) is true.  But to do this you can show (ii) is true.  You can also show (iii) is true, if you prefer. (You can do this instead. To do it in addition is redundant.) Note though that there is an error in (iii). It should be $h h'^{-1} \in H$ for all $h,h' \in H$.

Then, you use the wrong operation. The term $hh'$ means the "product" of the two elements $h,h'$ according to the group law in question, which is composition of maps.

Your $h$ is a maps that takes $x $ to $ax+b$. 
Your $h'$ is a map that takes $x$ to $a'x+b'$.

So $h h' $ is a map that takes $x$ to $a(h'(x))+b = a(a'x+b')+b$. Some further simplification will show it is of the desired form.

Likewise $h^{-1}$ is the inverse as a function. To determine it consider $y = ax+b$ and 'solve' for $x$ to find that the inverse function is the map that takes $y$ to $(y-b)/a = a^{-1}y + a^{-1}b$. So is indeed of the desired form.

To be precise, you might want to start of your argument with asserting that $x$ to $ax+b$ indeed is a bijective function. That would correspond to  asserting that $H$ even is a subset of $G$.